# Detect when user first types and last types and not in between

Tags: javascript

I have a case where I want a function to fire only when I first type something and fires another function when the I'm done typing (10 seconds idle)

I have this:

```
var keyPressElements = document.querySelectorAll('#waste-form input,#address,.container .form-control,.widget-box .form-control,#aria-main-search-form-field,#footer-search-field,#aria-feedback-form-field');
keyPressElements.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
        updateLastTypedTime();
    });
});
    
function updateLastTypedTime() {
    if (searchTimeout != undefined)
        clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    isUserTyping = true;
    console.log("Telling UpdateViewAPI that the user is still typing...");
    UpdateViewAPI();
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(callServerScript, 10000);
}

function callServerScript() {
        console.log("Telling UpdateViewAPI that the user hasn't typed in 10 seconds.");
        isUserTyping = false;
        UpdateViewAPI();
    }
```

But the issue with this is it triggers the updateLastTypedTime() everytime i type.

Thanks!

Comment: Well it should call updateLastTypedTime  because you call it on every keypress.... The code inside appears to do what you want where it cancels the timeout. You do not seem to have a check to say it is the first time something was typed.

Comment: It did not fly over my head... You just need to add a check if it is active, if not, you know it is the first time. `if(!isUserTyping) { /* you know it is first time */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want another function that's called from `updateLastTypedTime` only if the user was not already typing, something like:

```
function updateLastTypedTime() {
        if (searchTimeout != undefined)
            clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
        if (!isUserTyping)
            updateStartTyping();
        isUserTyping = true;
        searchTimeout = setTimeout(callServerScript, 10000);
    }
```

```js
var keyPressElements = document.querySelectorAll("#test-input");
keyPressElements.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
        updateLastTypedTime();
    });
});

var searchTimeout;
var isUserTyping = false;
    
function updateLastTypedTime() {
    if (searchTimeout != undefined)
        clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    if (!isUserTyping)
        updateStartTyping();
    isUserTyping = true;
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(callServerScript, 10000);
}

function updateStartTyping() {
  console.log("User started typing");
}

function callServerScript() {
    console.log("User stopped typing.");
    isUserTyping = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test-input">
```